# Produce a JSONP with a ContainerRequestContext#abortWith

Tags: jersey, jsonp, jersey-2.0

I have this Jersey2-based application, with a custom `ContainerRequestFilter`.

When the `filter(ContainerRequestContext)` method is called I want to do a check and, if needed, I want to be able to stop the request before entering the main logic of the application.
At the moment I'm using the `ContainerRequestContext#abortWith` method to block the call and return an "error" response to the client.

My application returns `JSONP` to the client, and if I block with `abortWith` the response is always a `JSON`.

Looking at the jersey sources I found 
`org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor` that is responsible of the `JSONP` serialization.
In the `abortWith` flow I see it fails to find the `JSONP` annotation, but I don't know where it search for it.

My method has it, in fact in the "normal" scenario (without the `abortWith`) I see correctly the `JSONP` format.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The `ContainerRequestFilter#filter` method was something like

```
public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext crc) throws IOException {
    if (/* logic */) {
        CustomObject ret = new CustomObject();
        ret.error = "error message";
        crc.abortWith(Response.ok(ret)).build());
    }
}
```

`JsonWithPaddingInterceptor` expected a response with a `JSONP` annotation so I retrieve them from the `ResourceInfo#resourceMethod`, with something like

```
public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext crc) throws IOException {
    if (/* logic */) {
        Annotation[] as = this.resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotations();

        CustomObject ret = new CustomObject();
        ret.error = "error message";
        crc.abortWith(Response.ok().entity(ret, as).build());
    }
}
```

this way the annotation is correctly found